# Cakephp finds result but Entity does not contain result

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a table called "services" with the field servicenumber.
A Servicenumber can occur in multiple rows and I want to find the services which share the same servicenumber with

```
$service = $this->Services->findByServiceGroupId(198)->contain(['RelatedServices'])->first();
```

My relation in ServicesTable is

```
$this->hasMany('RelatedServices', [
            'foreignKey' => 'servicenumber',
            'bindingKey' => ['Services.servicenumber', 'Services.id',  'Services.service_group_id'],
            'className' => 'Services',
            'strategy' => 'subquery',
            'finder' => 'related',
            'conditions' => [
                'Services.service_group_id != RelatedServices.service_group_id'
            ]
]);
```

Finder:

```
public function findRelated(Query $query, array $options = []): Query
    {
        $query = $query->select(['service_id' => 'Services.id', 'id' => 'RelatedServices.id'], false)->enableAutoFields(true);

        return $query;
    }
```

This produces following SQL

```
SELECT 
  Services.id AS service_id, 
  RelatedServices.id AS id, 
  RelatedServices.id AS RelatedServices__id, 
  RelatedServices.prefix AS RelatedServices__prefix, 
  RelatedServices.suffix AS RelatedServices__suffix, 
  RelatedServices.count AS RelatedServices__count, 
  RelatedServices.service_group_id AS RelatedServices__service_group_id, 
  RelatedServices.customer_id AS RelatedServices__customer_id, 
  RelatedServices.name AS RelatedServices__name, 
  RelatedServices.status AS RelatedServices__status, 
  RelatedServices.servicenumber AS RelatedServices__servicenumber 
FROM 
  services RelatedServices 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      (Services.servicenumber), 
      (Services.id), 
      (Services.service_group_id) 
    FROM 
      services Services 
      INNER JOIN customers Customers ON Customers.id = Services.customer_id 
      INNER JOIN service_groups ServiceGroups ON ServiceGroups.id = Services.service_group_id 
    WHERE 
      (
        Services.service_group_id = 198 
        AND Services.status = 'active'
      ) 
    GROUP BY 
      Services.servicenumber, 
      Services.id, 
      Services.service_group_id
  ) Services ON RelatedServices.servicenumber = Services.servicenumber 
WHERE 
  Services.service_group_id != RelatedServices.service_group_id
```

This query finds the correct result(s) but my service-entity still has an empty related_services array.

How can I do that cakephp connects the results to my original service-entity?

Comment: Are you tried select fields in `contain`?

Comment: Yes, in my Finder-method. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I was going to ask about `contain` too but I can't clarify your comment about it because I've yet to understand `findByServiceGroupId`. Is this a custom finder made by you? And are you using CakePHP4 or CakePHP3?

Comment: It's a dynamic-finder built-in by cakephp. I'm using cakephp 4.4.
https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#dynamic-finders

Comment: Interesting. Then two things strike me. From that doc link of dynamic finders, "Other query options like contain are also not supported with dynamic finders." so your `$this->Services->findByServiceGroupId(198)->contain(['RelatedServices'])->first();` shouldn't work? Your `hasMany` has three "bindingKey" columns but just one related "foreignKey" column. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Now I stripped Services.id and Services.service_group_id from my bindingKey-array. I also removed the conditions-array.
Now I my entity contains the related services but also itself because I can not filter anymore for unequal service-ids or service_group-ids.
So now I have to remove the "extra"-entity programmatically.